# Android и нативный select

Tags: android, html, css

Возможно с помощью css у `option` в `optgroup` убрать отступ на андроиде?

Firefox, Android 4.4.4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да можно, только нужно ваш код посмотреть сначало

Comment: @Saidolim, зачем? это же нативный элемент